# Python in vscode: Import errors do not show up in terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm writing python scripts in vscode and recently I've been having a problem related to imports.
Lines of code above imports work and their output is displayed in the terminal:

```
print("hellow")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
#from scipy.special import erfc
from scipy.linalg import solve

> hellow
```

Lines of code below the imports are not executed, but no errors are displayed in the terminal!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
#from scipy.special import erfc
from scipy.linalg import solve
print("hellow")

>
```

I'm guessing there is something wrong with my vscode settings, but why are no errors showing up in the terminal?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't think this is related to your vscode settings. Can you identify a specific import that blocks your program (try to put the hello just after the plt import, then np, then solve)?

Comment: you're right there is something wrong with matplotlib. I can import maplotlib, but when I try to import matplotlib.pyplot then python crashes. This doesn't just happen in vscode.

Comment: Could you try that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53088313/10144963

Comment: @Crawdad_Buckwheat, you can try to uninstall `matplotlib` and reinstall it to see if the problem goes away.

Comment: Ok, I was able to get around the problem. First I tried uninstalling and reinstalling matplotlib with pip (didn't work). Then I tried installing matplotlib with conda (didn't work). It seems there may be a conflict between my windows 10 and the latest version of numpy or matplotlib. I downgraded to numpy version 1.19.3 and matplotlib 3.1.2 and now things are working again.