# Matplotlib Plotting crashes Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda, spyder, jupyter-lab

I have installed Python via Anaconda on my newer more powerful laptop and it is having this issue that I never experienced in my older less powerful laptop. I can easily and smoothly create plots and interact with them in MATLAB and SciLab, but when I try to plot in Python, anything that would normally cause the matplotlib figure GUI window to appear will result in Python crashing.

For example,

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
plot([1,2,3])
show()
```

This happens invariably whether I am in the Anaconda Prompt, Spyder IDE Ipython Console, or JupyterLab Python console. I would get the `Python has stopped working` error message everytime. As a result, I can't plot anything with matplotlib

I have already searched and tried how to remedy this. I tried the solutions already several times in this stackoverflow question: [matplotlib crashing Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26955017/matplotlib-crashing-python)

```
pip install PyQt5
```

or

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
```

I still get the error messages. I'm already thinking that maybe I should just install Python without Anaconda and add the packages I need individually, but I'm afraid that this issue maybe endemic to the laptop itself so I would still get the error messages regardless.

Can anybody help me out?